# how to read ajax response with multiple objects in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get the multiple eloquent objects through controller json response when drop down is changed.

[image]

When cinema hall is changed then it should return 2 objects fetched from 2 different tables.

controller code

```
 public function getscreen($id)
{
    $screens=Movies_screen::where('cinema_id',$id)->get();
    $showtime=Movies_showtimes::where('cinema_id',$id)->get();

    return response()->json($screens);
}
```

my jquery ajax code

```
 $("#cinemahall").on("change click",function(){

var cinema_id=$("#cinemahall option:selected").val();
//ajax
    $.get('/askspidy/admin/showtime/getscreen/' + cinema_id, function(data){

        $("#screenname").empty();
        $("#screenname").append('<option value=0>Select Screen</option>');

        $.each(data,function(index,screenobj){
            $("#screenname").append('<option value="' +screenobj.screen_id + '">' +screenobj.screen_name +'</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

The above code works fine when single eloquent object is sent i.e $screens , but as you can see in code there is another object i.e $showtime and i need to send the same with that request and read it in my jquery ajax code.

I tried in controller

```
 public function getscreen($id)
{
    $screens=Movies_screen::where('cinema_id',$id)->get();
    $showtime=Movies_showtimes::where('cinema_id',$id)->get();

    return response()->json($screens,$showtime);
}
```

and in jquery code

```
 $.get('/askspidy/admin/showtime/getscreen/' + cinema_id, function(data,data2)
```

but none of the solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return an array with indexes pointing to the different collections:

```
return response()->json(['screens' => $screens, 'showtime' => $showtime]);
```

In JSON, this will be translated to a Javascript object with two properties, 'screens' and 'showtime':

```
$.get('/askspidy/admin/showtime/getscreen/' + cinema_id, function(data) {
    console.log(data.screens);
    console.log(data.showtime);
});
```

Comment: its working but need one help, i am trying to get this displayed as  $.each(data,function(index,screenobj){
                $("#screenname").append('<option value="' +screenobj.screens[0] + '">' +screenobj.screens[0] +'</option>');
            });      but its' not working , can you figure out the problem. Thanks

Comment: @dollar Please open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Return your response in an array:

```
return response()->json(["screens" => $screens, "showtime" => $showtime]);
```

Then access via your `GET` request using `.` syntax for JS objects:

```
$.get("URL", function(data){ 
    console.log(data.screens);
    // or 
    console.log(data.showtimes);
});
```